# Parsing CDATA content from webservice response in Java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, cdata, string-parsing

I'm making a webservice call in my Java code and getting the response as String with the below data.

```
<DocumentElement>
   <ResultSet>
     <Response>Successfully Sent.</Response>
     <UsedCredits>1</UsedCredits>
   </ResultSet>
</DocumentElement>
```

Now, I want to parse the below response String and get the value of `<Response>` tag alone for further processing. Since, I'm getting only the CDATA content how to parse the String content?

Comment: @mzjn The data given above is contained inside the CDATA section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You obviously need XML parser for this one. Lets say the above is stored in a `String` variable named `content`

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
          //Using factory get an instance of document builder
           DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
           InputSource is = new InputSource();
           is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(content)); //content variable holding xml records         
           Document doc = db.parse(is)
           /* Now retrieve data from xml */
           NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("ResultSet");
           Element elm = (Element) nodes.item(0);   //will get you <Response> Successfully Sent.</Response>
           String responseText = elm.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

    }catch(ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }catch(SAXException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Follow the above parser routine for larger data sets. Use loops for multiple similar data sets. Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, since you being a new user, don't forget to tick check the arrow  on the left of this answer if you find it helpful.

Comment: Where can I find code for `getCharacterDataFromElement` method?

Comment: Sorry, my apologies. I forgot to include that. My answer is now updated.